# How to render at a fixed FPS in a GLFW window?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw

I am trying to render at 60 FPS but my scene is rendering at a much higher rate than 60 FPS.

This is my code for the Render Loop, is this the correct way to render at a desired FPS or are there better ways?

```
double lastTime = glfwGetTime(), timer = lastTime;
double deltaTime = 0, nowTime = 0;
int frames = 0, updates = 0;

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
// input
// -----
processInput(window);
// - Measure time
nowTime = glfwGetTime();
deltaTime += (nowTime - lastTime) / limitFPS;  // limitFPS = 1.0 / 60.0
lastTime = nowTime;

// - Only update at 60 frames / s
while (deltaTime >= 1.0) {
    updates++;
    deltaTime--;
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT |  GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    w.render();  // Render function
    frames++; 
}

glfwPollEvents();

// - Reset after one second
if (glfwGetTime() - timer > 1.0) {
    timer++;

}
glfwSwapBuffers(window);

}
```

Comment: Smells like C++ from here.  Is that the case?  If so, are you aware of the `std:chrono` family of classes introduced in C++11?  In particular, [`std::this_thread::sleep_for()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)?

Comment: @genfault that is what i would like to know , would sleep be a good way of handling this.

Comment: Well, it's either that or hope your system has functional [vsync](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__context.html#ga6d4e0cdf151b5e579bd67f13202994ed) :)

Comment: @genpfault i have turned on vertical sync in the nvidia card  would that be enough ?

Comment: The first question is: Why would you want to cap to 60 fps? If you want to avoid rendering what cannot be displayed, try `glfwSwapInterval(1)`.

Comment: @Nico Schertler this is a Serial digital interface (SDI) application so i need to cap my fps to 60 on a VGA machine and 50 on a machine with SDI output card with reference

Comment: The output card needs 50 FPS to display.

Comment: An important detail we need before answering your question is whether you want the FPS *and* update logic to be fixed at 60hz, or do you want the frame rate decoupled from the update rate?

Comment: So have you tried `glfwSwapInterval(1)`?

Comment: @Romen i want the frame rate to be decoupled from the update rate.

Comment: @Nico Schertler i want to cap the frame rate from the function itself as this is supposed to be 60FPS on VGA machines and 50 FPS on machines with bluefish SDI  cards.

Comment: Could you please just try it and tell us if it works? Another common way of doing it is a structure like this: `while(running) { logic_update(); if(now - last_render > frame_update_time) render(); }`, where `frame_update_time` is `1 / frame rate`.

Comment: @Nico Schertler yes  using glfwSwapInterval(1) caps the refresh rate to the vertical sync  of the  graphics card , the reason why i want a function is that the frame update for maching with SDI output card would be 50 so vertical sync would be switched off in those machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the discussion in comments above, you want to draw a maximum of 60 FPS, but you want the logic to update as often as possible. Correct?

That can be achieved with just one loop, a timer, and an if statement:

```c++
const double fpsLimit = 1.0 / 60.0;
double lastUpdateTime = 0;  // number of seconds since the last loop
double lastFrameTime = 0;   // number of seconds since the last frame

// This while loop repeats as fast as possible
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    double now = glfwGetTime();
    double deltaTime = now - lastUpdateTime;

    glfwPollEvents();

    // update your application logic here,
    // using deltaTime if necessary (for physics, tweening, etc.)

    // This if-statement only executes once every 60th of a second
    if ((now - lastFrameTime) >= fpsLimit)
    {
        // draw your frame here

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        // only set lastFrameTime when you actually draw something
        lastFrameTime = now;
    }

    // set lastUpdateTime every iteration
    lastUpdateTime = now;
}
```

Everything that you want to execute as often as possible should be in the outer part of that `while` loop, and everything you want to execute at a maximum of 60 times per second should be inside the `if` statement.

If the loop takes longer than 1/60th of a second to execute an iteration then your FPS and update rate will drop to whatever rate is achievable for that workload/system.

Comment: it doesn't work, the mouse action not response in this way

Comment: This answer is only meant to be a reference; Not 100% working code that everyone can just drop in place. The `glfwPollEvents()` call *should* handle mouse input but there are different ways of doing that on different platforms and input types. Change it to do what works for your use case.